# How to minimize if else conditions for mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

**NEED:**

I need to select all the value in the field of table using MySql query when the condition is false.

Below i show few codes only because the db fields are large.

**Code:**

```
<?php 
include "db.php";
$type1=$_POST['type'];
if($type1=='all')
{
   $type='*';
}
else
{
$type=$type1;
}
$selecttype=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM product where type='$type'");
?>
```

I Konw the `*` is not correct. Just i am used for example to select all.

But when i use the above code the query is not success. What is the solution of this?

**MY FULL CODE:**

```
    <?php

        $sort=$_POST['sort'];
        $city=$_POST['city'];
        $location=$_POST['location'];
        $type=$_POST['type'];
        $res_type=$_POST['res_type'];
        $cus_type=$_POST['cus_type'];

                            $i=0;
                            include "db.php";
                            if($sort=='name')
                               $sort_by='name';
                            else
                               $sort_by=null;  


                            if($city!=null && $location!=null && $sort!=null)
                            {                                   

                                if($type=='cod')
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where cod='on' and type='$res_type' and city='$city' and location='$location' ORDER BY $sort_by ");      
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where cod='on' and type='$res_type' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type' and city='$city' and location='$location' ORDER BY $sort_by ");      
                                    }

                                }
                                else if($type=='pickup')
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where pickup='on' and type='$res_type' and city='$city' and location='$location' ORDER BY $sort_by ");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {  
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where pickup='on' and type='$res_type' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type' and city='$city' and location='$location' ORDER BY $sort_by ");
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where city='$city' and type='$res_type' and location='$location' ORDER BY $sort_by ");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where city='$city' and type='$res_type' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type' and location='$location' ORDER BY $sort_by ");        
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                            else if($city!=null && $location==null && $sort!=null)
                            {                                   

                                if($type=='cod')
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where cod='on' and type='$res_type' and city='$city' ORDER BY $sort_by ");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where cod='on' and type='$res_type' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type'and city='$city' ORDER BY $sort_by ");
                                    }

                                }
                                else if($type=='pickup')
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where pickup='on' and type='$res_type' and city='$city'  ORDER BY $sort_by ");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where pickup='on' and type='$res_type' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type' and city='$city'  ORDER BY $sort_by ");
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where city='$city' and type='$res_type' ORDER BY $sort_by ");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where city='$city' and type='$res_type' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type'  ORDER BY $sort_by ");        
                                    }

                                }
                            }


                            else if($city!=null && $location!=null && $sort==null)
                            {

                                if($type=='cod')
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where cod='on' and  city='$city' and location='$location' and type='$res_type' ");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where cod='on' and  city='$city' and location='$location' and  cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type' and type='$res_type' ");        
                                    }

                                }
                                else if($type=='pickup')
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where pickup='on' and  city='$city'  and type='$res_type' and location='$location' ");    
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where pickup='on' and  city='$city'  and type='$res_type' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type' and location='$location' ");    
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where city='$city' and type='$res_type' and location='$location' "); 
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where city='$city' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type'  and type='$res_type' and location='$location' ");         
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                            else if($city!=null && $location==null && $sort==null)
                            {

                                if($type=='cod')
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where cod='on' and  city='$city' and type='$res_type' ");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where cod='on' and  city='$city' and FIND_IN_SET('$cus_type', cusine_type) and type='$res_type' ");        
                                    }

                                }
                                else if($type=='pickup')
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where pickup='on' and  city='$city' and type='$res_type' ");  
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where pickup='on' and  city='$city' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type' and type='$res_type' ");          
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where city='$city' and type='$res_type' ");  
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where city='$city'  and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type' and type='$res_type' ");          
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                            else if($city==null && $location==null && $sort==null)
                            {


                                if($type=='cod')
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where cod='on' and  type='$res_type' ");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where cod='on' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type' and  type='$res_type' ");        
                                    }

                                }
                                else if($type=='pickup')
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where pickup='on' and type='$res_type' ");    
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where pickup='on' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type' and type='$res_type' ");            
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where  type='$res_type ");   
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where  type='$res_type' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type' ");   
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                            else if($city==null && $location==null && $sort!=null)
                            {

                                if($type=='cod')
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where cod='on' and  type='$res_type'  ORDER BY $sort_by ");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where cod='on' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type' and  type='$res_type'  ORDER BY $sort_by ");        
                                    }

                                }
                                else if($type=='pickup')
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where pickup='on' and type='$res_type'  ORDER BY $sort_by ");    
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where pickup='on' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type' and type='$res_type'  ORDER BY $sort_by ");    
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if($cus_type=='all')
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where type='$res_type' ORDER BY $sort_by ");  
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where type='$res_type' and cusine_type REGEXP '$cus_type' ORDER BY $sort_by ");          
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                            while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($qy))
                            {   
                                $id=$res['id'];
                                $name=$res['name'];
                                $image=$res['logo'];
                                $desciption=$res['description'];
                                $cod=$res['cod'];
                                $pickup=$res['pickup'];
                                $min_order=$res['min_order'];
                                $i++;
                            ?>
// Some HTML Code with PHP
                            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: If the type is some other means, i need to write another line. Can i write MySql code as single for above condition?

Comment: what field do you have in your database and what do need. accordingly query can be fired.....

Comment: the fields in my db is large. So only i write few and necessary condition is my question

Answer (score 1):

change your code to be like this instead:

```
<?php 
include "db.php";
$type1=$_POST['type'];

if($type1=='all')
    $type="Where 1=1";
else
   $type='Where type = "'.$type1.'"';

$selecttype = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM product ".$type);
?>
```

**EDIT**
This also works on multiple conditions, all you have to do is to append value to the `$type` variable like this:

```
if($type1=='all')
    $type="Where 1=1";
else
   $type='Where type = "'.$type1.'"';

if($somethingElse == "example")
    $type .= ' AND somethingElse = "'.$somethingElse.'"';
```

Comment: Thanks... This will work. But when use many condition in where this is possible?.


Please see my updated question.

Comment: yes it is possible, you can always append something to the `$type` variable

Comment: See my Full Code. When the `$res_type='all', $cus_type='all' and $type='all'` the how can i write this?

Comment: @user2784198 I edited my answer to show example of multiple conditions

Comment: Thanks Friend. I am going to try this. Thanks for spending your time to answer me

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need `if statement`. Try this :

```
<?php 
include "db.php";
$type1=$_POST['type'];
$selecttype=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM product where type='$type1' or '$type1'= 'all'");
?>
```

**Edit:**

You don't need so many `if condition`. Just change your full code like this. Please try it and give some feedback, I'm not tested this, but his should works.

```
<?php
        $sort=$_POST['sort'];
        $city=$_POST['city'];
        $location=$_POST['location'];
        $type=$_POST['type'];
        $res_type=$_POST['res_type'];
        $cus_type=$_POST['cus_type'];

        $i=0;
        include "db.php";

        if ($city!=null) {$qy_city = " AND city='$city' ";} else {$qy_city = " ";}
        if ($location!=null) {$qy_location = " AND location='$location' ";} else {$qy_location = " ";}
        if ($sort!=null) {$qy_sort = " ORDER BY $sort ";} else {$qy_sort = " ";}
        $query = "SELECT * FROM add_res where ".$type."='on' 
                   AND (cusine_type = '".$cus_type."' OR 'all' = '".$cus_type."')
                   AND (type = '".$res_type."' OR 'all' = '".$res_type."')".$qy_city.$qy_location.qy_sort;     
        $qy=mysqli_query($con, $query);

        while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($qy))
        {   
            $id=$res['id'];
            $name=$res['name'];
            $image=$res['logo'];
            $desciption=$res['description'];
            $cod=$res['cod'];
            $pickup=$res['pickup'];
            $min_order=$res['min_order'];
            $i++;
        ?>
        // Some HTML Code with PHP
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @user2784198 Yes, and you don't need so many `if condition` like that.

Comment: Thanks Friend. I am going to try this one also

Comment: @user2784198 by `$type1=='all'` are you referring to all the types, or to just records whose type is "all"? if you are referring to the 2nd option, then @RubanMalan is right

Comment: I am referring all the types.

Comment: @user2784198 I updated my answer. You need to modify your full code.

Comment: @user2784198  if this or any answer has solved your question please mark it as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try this is the Answer.

```
if($type1=='all')
{
  $selecttype=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM product");
}
else
{
$type=$type1;
$selecttype=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM product where type='$type'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i am get the output for above my question with less code.

*THANKS FOR ALL THE ALL:*

**MY NEW FULL CODE:**

```
<?php        
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $location=$_POST['location'];
    $type=$_POST['type']; 
    $sort=$_POST['sort']; 
    $res_type=$_POST['res_type']; 
    $cus_type=$_POST['cus_type'];

    $i=0;
    include "db.php";               

    $query=" WHERE 1=1 ";
    // FOR CITY
    if($city!=null)
        $query .=' AND city="'.$city.'"';          
    // FOR LOCATION
    if($location!=null)
        $query .= ' AND location = "'.$location.'"';
    // FOR TYPE
    if($type=='cod')
        $query .= ' AND cod = "on"';
    else if($type=='pickup')
        $query .= ' AND pickup ="on"';
    // FOR SORT
    if($sort=='name')
        $sort_query= "ORDER BY $sort";
    else
        $sort_query=null;
    // FOR RES_TYPE
    if($res_type!=null)
       $query .= ' AND type="'.$res_type.'"';
    // FOR CUSINE_TYPE
    if($cus_type!='all')
        $query .= ' AND FIND_IN_SET(\''.$cus_type.'\',cusine_type)';

   $qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res ".$query.$sort_query);

    while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($qy))
    {   
        $id=$res['id'];
    ?>
    // Some HTML Code with PHP
    <?php } ?>
```